# Is there a way to add arguments as variables to execute a command line instruction from inside a python file

Tags: python, python-3.x, command-line

I have a file
buyfruits.py
this parses the arguments and sends them to a file called buying.py
for eg this command:
$python buyfruits.py --quantity 20 --amount 50 --fruit apple

will result in buy 20  apples for 50 coins

I want this to take arguments from another file

let's say input.py

```
amt = input("Enter amount ")
q = input("Enter quantity you want")
what = input("Enter fruit you want to buy ")
```

i want this input.py file to execute this code

$python buyfruits.py --quantity q --amount amt --fruit what

Comment: why not just make the logic in `buyfruits` enclosed in a function you could just import into input.py?.. (or call the fields from input.py from your other file)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use os.system:

```py
import os

amt = input("Enter amount ")
q = input("Enter quantity you want")
what = input("Enter fruit you want to buy ")

os.system("buyfruits.py --quantity %s --amount %s --fruit %s" % (q, amt, what))
```

or subprocess, if you want to capture the output of buyfruits.py:

```py
import subprocess, shlex # shlex needed for command-line splitting

amt = input("Enter amount ")
q = input("Enter quantity you want")
what = input("Enter fruit you want to buy ")

p = subprocess.Popen(shlex.split("buyfruits.py --quantity %s --amount %s --fruit %s" % (q, amt, what)))
print("output : %s\nerrors : %s" % p.communicate()) # print output and errors of the process
```

Comment: This worked , Thanks a lot. How do i mark it solved?

Comment: @Aavesh click the checkbox on the right of my answer !

Comment: @Aavesh well i meant the grey checkmark on the LEFT of my answer, it will turn green.

Comment: @Aavesh by accepting an answer you get +2 reputation, by the way

Comment: Done, my ad-blocker was blocking he the checkbox , great answer.

Comment: @Aavesh YOUR ADBLOCKER BLOCKED THE CHECKBOX ... WOW

Answer (score 0):

Read about python **subprocess** module.

```
#I assume you are using Python3.x
import subprocess
amt = input("Enter amount ")
q = input("Enter quantity you want")
what = input("Enter fruit you want to buy ")
output=subprocess.check_output(['buyfruits.py', '--quantity', q, '--amount', amt, '--fruit', what], shell=True)
print(output)
```

you can use call,check_call as well.

Answer (score -1):

you can use getopt and sys libraries

```
import getopt, sys
def get_arguments():
    fruit = None
    quantity = None
    amount = None
    argv = sys.argv[1:]
    opts, argv = getopt.getopt(argv, "a:q:f:")
    for opt, argv in opts:
        if opt in ['-a']:
            amount = argv
        elif opt in ['-q']:
            quantity = argv
        elif opt in ['-f']:
            fruit = argv
            
    print('amount : {}'.format(amount))
    print('quantity : {}'.format(quantity))
    print('fruit : {}'.format(fruit))

get_arguments()
```

input:

> $python file_1.py -a 20 -q 5 -f apple

output:

> amount : 20
> quantity : 5
> fruit : apple

Comment: one downvote : this code is not portable (works only with python3), because of `str.format()`

Comment: sorry but he tag python3 not python2

Comment: your code may work for him, but not for other people coming across this and trying this code with python2.

Comment: @frederic No one uses python2, it reached its end of life. If someone uses it, its *their* problem.